# Add a row to JTable once the last cell has lost focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Any suggestions on how to add another row to a JTable once the last column has lost focus, accounting for movable columns?

Note: The table is populated by user input but I would only like to show a new empty row once the current row is filled out.

Comment: How does the reordering of columns or the selection status affect in any way the method by which you populate the table?

Comment: The table is populated by user input but I would only like to show a new empty row once the current row is filled out.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, remember when writing your questions that we know nothing about what are you doing. There's a couple of aproaches I can think immediately, either when your CellEditor stops editing or with a TableModelListener, on data change, check if you want to add a new empty row to the table (that is: you were editing the last row and you are done with it). The first one is probably cleaner. You might also want to pass the focus to the first cell of the new row. The problem would be what happens when you don't want to add more rows, are you left with an empty row at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple application that behaves as required:

- You can edit any cell and once the last cell of the last row editing ends an empty row is added.
- It supports column reordering (no extra effort was required for this).

The approach is actually quite simple, `JTable` implements [`CellEditorListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/CellEditorListener.html), so we can override the method `editingStopped(ChangeEvent)` and check if we are in the last cell of the table and if so add a new row.

So you should do something like this:

```
//In the JTable class    
    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) 
    {
        //getting these values before calling super.editingStopped(e); because they get erased.
        int row = getEditingRow();
        int col = getEditingColumn();
        super.editingStopped(e); //must call the super code to have a working edition
        if (row == getRowCount() - 1 && col == getColumnCount() - 1)
        {
            getModel().createNewRow();
        }
    };
```

Obviously the TableModel and TableCellEditor and JTable I implemented are the bare minimum to accomplish this, you can use your own, just change the calls to the model I use for yours.

It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I recommend using TAB to finish editing so the focus goes to the next one, and when you are in the last it jumps to the first of the new row.

Full code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


public class TableEditingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new TableEditingTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table editing test");

        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        model.addRow(new String[]{"Some values", "so we have", "an actual table."});
        model.addRow(new String[]{"This table", "is inititalized", "with an empty row:"});
        model.createNewRow();

        MyTable table = new MyTable(model);

        table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new MyStringTableCellEditor());

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        frame.setSize(600, 400); //use frame.pack() in a real application
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyTable extends JTable
    {
        public MyTable(MyTableModel model)
        {
            super(model);
        }

        @Override
        public MyTableModel getModel()
        {
            return (MyTableModel) super.getModel();
        }

        @Override
        public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) 
        {
            int row = getEditingRow();
            int col = getEditingColumn();
            super.editingStopped(e);
            if (row == getRowCount() - 1 && col == getColumnCount() - 1)
            {
                getModel().createNewRow();
            }   
        };
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 3;
        private ArrayList<String[]> values;


        public MyTableModel()
        {
            values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return "Column " + col;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col)
        {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
        {
            return true;
        };

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return values.get(row)[col];
        }

        public void createNewRow()
        {
            addRow(null);
        }

        public void addRow(String[] rowValues)
        {
            if (rowValues == null) 
            {
                values.add(new String[3]);
                fireTableDataChanged();
            }
            else if (rowValues.length == 3)
            {
                values.add(rowValues);
                fireTableDataChanged();
            }
            else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected an array of " + NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS + " strings, got " + rowValues.length + ".");
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            values.get(row)[col] = value.toString();
        }
    }

    private class MyStringTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
    {
        private JTextField editorField = new JTextField();

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue()
        {
            return editorField.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
        {
            editorField.setText((String) value);
            return editorField;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend that you should use `TAB` key `ActionMap` instead of using focus lost.

For adding a new row you can use your `DeafultTableModel`

```
 public void addNewRow(){
     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
       Vector row = new Vector();
       row.add(null);
       row.add(null);
       row.add(null);
       model.addRow(row);
    }
```

For the trigger that will can the above method to execute you can use `InputMap` & `ActionMap`

```
 private class NextCellActioin extends AbstractAction{

    public NextCellActioin() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       int col = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
       int row =jTable1.getSelectedRow();
       int colCount = jTable1.getColumnCount();
       int rowCount = jTable1.getRowCount(); 
         col++;
        if (col >= colCount) {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
        if (row >= rowCount) {
           row = 0;
        }
           jTable1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
           jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(col, col);
           jTable1.editCellAt(row, col);
        if(col==3 && row==rowCount-1) {
           addNewRow();
           jTable1.scrollRectToVisible(jTable1.getCellRect(rowCount,0, true)); 
        }

    }
}
```

To initialize the `InputMap` & `ActionMap`

```
jTable1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "Action.NextCell");
jTable1.getActionMap().put("Action.NextCell", new NextCellActioin());
```